# Upload 18000 PDFs to Azure wwwroot/uploads floder using Kudu

Tags: azure, pdf, kudu, azureportal

[Screen Shot added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfrUv.png)

I want to upload PDFs to azure webapp folder and i used Kudu service to do this. but when i drag and drop into area all are seems to have uploading but at the end it will only show 199 files. i'm new to windows azure services and any one have idea? Hope you all understand my issue.

Thanks..!

Comment: There's a display limit in the Kudu UI, and 200 items seems to be that limit. All the files are there, just do a `dir` in the console below.

Comment: Indeed, as @evilSnobu says, the limit is on the display, and the files are probably there.

Comment: @evilSnobu  thank you for your response..

Comment: @DavidEbbo thank you for your response too..

Answer (score 1):

You could just package them as a Zip file and drag-n-drop that to Kudu, it will extract it automatically for you.